# Elastic Search Query that identifies not only the results but also highlights the items that satisfy a particular attribute

Tags: elasticsearch

We have a requirement that we think is a candidate for a Multi-Search query but we are not sure.

Say we are selling clothes.
The user can enter a type of clothing such as Shirts and we bring back all the shirts using a filter.

We would also like to provide the user with an option of them typing in a keyword such as "formal" or "beach" etc. But this keyword should not effect the results but identify with a flag which items in the results these keywords appear.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What about using [Named Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-queries-and-filters)?

The ideas is that this feature of Elasticsearch allows users to mark each clause in the query with a `_name` value identifying the particular clause.  If the particular clauses, say a clause with "formal" keyword or a clause with "beach" keyword", are matched, the response will include a `matched_queries` prop with each result noting which particular item was matched.

Another option might be to use [Highlights](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-highlighting).  The feature does allow you to specify a separate [highlighting query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/search-request-body.html#specify-highlight-query).  However, the response format here may not be as straightforward or meet your requirements.